# Is there any way to install iOS extension without installing the container application?

Tags: ios, today-extension, ios-extensions

I want to implement a today extension only, that is, for this I don't want to create an application for doing this. Is there any way to install a today extension only, without installing the container app? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The container app is required for extensions. That's why they're called extensions, not standalone applications. The container app can sit in the phone and stay inactive but it must be there for an extension to exist.

Comment: @rkr_stack please mark as correct if the information is useful so other users can refer to this answer :-)